# Terragrunt download module from specific branch

Tags: git, terraform, terragrunt

I started recently using terragrunt and have been wondering if it's possible to download module from specific branch not specfic tag ( or in addition to tag ) rather than by default master

Download specific tag from master:

```sh
terraform {
  source = "git@github.com:<repo>/infrastructure-modules.git//gcp/bucket?ref=v.0.0.1"
}
```

Download specific branch from repo ?

```sh
# Pseudo code
terraform {
  source = "git@github.com:<repo>/infrastructure-modules.git//gcp/bucket?ref=v.0.0.1%branch=test"
}
```

Comment: Did the `ref=<mybranch>` work?

Comment: nope, looks like tags work repository-wide , so I just made changes on branch, git add, git commit, git tag -a 'v1.branch', git push --follow-tags -u origin <branch_name>, and I could the tag reference to the branch not master

Comment: OK, good to know. I have edited the answer accordingly and included your comment for more vsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the terragrunt [`cli/download_source_test.go`](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/blob/fda1a473560b4fe932fea4d85d8ae9423d24b988/cli/download_source_test.go) source code, there is no apparent way to specify a branch.

That means you need to add a tag to that branch, and use that tag as `ref`.
That being said, check first if `ref=<mybranch>` works.

However, the [OP potatopotato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13115677/potatopotato) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62889868/terragrunt-download-module-from-specific-branch?noredirect=1#comment111252021_62889868) that referencing the branch name directly does not work.

> I just made changes on branch, and:
>
> ```
> git add
>  git commit
>  git tag -a 'v1.branch'
>  git push --follow-tags -u origin <branch_name>
> ```
>
> and I could use the tag reference to the branch, not `master`.

And [German Dautin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15335310/german-dautin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66489393/6309) points to [Terraform / Module Sources /  Selecting a Revision](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/sources.html#selecting-a-revision-1).

> By default, Terraform will clone and use the default branch (referenced by HEAD) in the selected repository. You can override this using the ref argument:
>
> ```yaml
> module "vpc" {
>   source = "git::https://example.com/vpc.git?ref=v1.2.0"
> }
> ```
>
> The value of the ref argument can be any reference that would be accepted by the git checkout command, including branch and tag names.

So using a branch name is possible.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to specify a branch using following:

```
terraform {
  source = "git@github.com:<repo>/infrastructure-modules.git//gcp/bucket?ref=branch-name"
}
```

Comment: Interesting: is there any documentation supporting this syntax?

Comment: it's clearly explained here
[link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/sources.html#selecting-a-revision-1)
The value of the ref argument can be any reference that would be accepted by the git checkout command, including branch and tag names.

Comment: @GermanDautin What happens if tag name is same as branch name. Just a curiosity.